# Probability with elements of geometry

Tags: probability

We have a wire of length 20. We bend this wire in random point. And then bend again to get rectangual frame. What's the probability that area of this rectangle is less than 21.

I think that we should use geometric probability, but I don't know how.

Comment: What is the pole?

Comment: It's an area. Bad translation.

Comment: Hint:  the point you choose, call it $x$ has to be between $0$ and $10$.  Let's say it's uniform (though you don't specify any distribution).  Then the other dimension is $10-x$ so the area is $x(10-x)$.

Comment: Do you mean that after your first bending, you select the longest part and bend this second part, not arbitrarily but in such a way that you obtain a kind of stapple (a "C" shape) and that is your rectangle ? Could you confirm or infirm my interpretation ?

Comment: This is not specified. You have to bend it 3x times to get a rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X\sim\mathsf U(0,20)$ be the point at which we first bend the pole. Then the height of the rectangle is $H=X\wedge20-X$ and the width of the rectangle is $W=2(10-H)$, so the area of the rectangle is $A=WH = 2H(10-H)$. The distribution of $H$ is $\mathsf U(0,10)$ by symmetry. To compute $$\mathbb P(A\leqslant 21) = \mathbb P(2H(10-H)\leqslant 21)=\mathbb P\left(H(10-H)\leqslant\frac{21}2\right), $$
consider the function $a(h)=h(10-h)$. We have $a'(h) = 10-2h$, so the maximum of $a$ is $25$, attained at $h=5$, with $a'$ negative on $(0,5)\cup(5,10)$. The equation
$$h(10-h)=\frac{21}2 $$
has solutions $h=5\pm\frac{\sqrt{58}}2$, so 
$$h(10-h)\leqslant \frac{21}2\iff h\in\left[0,5-\frac{\sqrt{58}}2\right]\cup\left[5+\frac{\sqrt{58}}2,10\right]. $$
By symmetry we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(H(10-H)\leqslant \frac{21}2 &= 2\mathbb P\left(H\leqslant 5-\frac{\sqrt{58}}2\right)\\&=2\cdot\frac1{10}\left(5-\frac{\sqrt{58}}2\right)\\
&= 1 - \frac{\sqrt{58}}{10}.
\end{align}